# Contact Professor before applying for Phd scholarship?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, funding

I am applying for Phd. funded scholarship in Australia here is the [link](https://www.qut.edu.au/study/fees-and-scholarships/scholarships/arc-linkage-funded-scholarship-revolutionising-high-resolution-water-quality-monitoring-in-the-information-age), in this link it is mention that you should contact professor before applying for the scholarship. I emailed him and his response was "There are selection criteria.  It would be worth responding to each of these as well as providing a CV".

My question is how can I provide proof about the selection criteria. Should I provide a cover later about that or just CV.

Comment: _Contact Professor before applying for Phd scholarship?_ Yes, do. _how can I provide proof about the selection criteria. Should I provide a cover later about that or just CV_ Yes, **provide a covering letter**.

Comment: do a google search for "address selection criteria" and look for guidance and examples. Doesn't have to be academic positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, send *three* things. The cover letter is introductory and speaks about your desire and basic qualifications for working with that professor. It is a sort of a Statement of Purpose. Also send the CV. But the third document is one that specifically addresses, in order, each item in the stated selection criteria and how you meet that criterion or that you have little to no experience with it. Make it an honest statement, not just empty claims. Point to items in the CV as necessary.

It is probably expected that you meet the criteria in general, but also expected  that each candidate will meet each item differently